# UITextField adding more than 1, spawn random

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

Wondering why when I drag the WhiteDot over the SmallDot it adds more than 1 to my UITextField? It varies from each time I run the iPhone simulator. Sometimes it adds 11, 2, 3, 5...etc. No idea why?
Another question, when the SmallDot disappears I also want it to spawn in a specified view. The Score is in top right corner.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

private var AddOne = 0

@IBOutlet weak var Score: UITextField!
}


@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    if (WhiteDot.frame.contains(SmallDot.frame)) {
        SmallDot.image = nil;
        AddOne += 1
        Score.text = "\(AddOne)"

    }


        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Expanding on Duncan's answer, you should try and use the `state` property of the gesture (`UIGestureRecognizerState`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided much information.

A pan gesture recognizer reports a continuous stream of coordinates as the user pans with their finger. You're probably getting multiple "hits" when you drag one dot over another. You need to have some sort of test to see if the smaller dot has been eaten yet. Since you're already setting the image on the small dot to nil, you could check that:

```
if (WhiteDot.frame.contains(SmallDot.frame) && SmallDot.image != nil) {
    SmallDot.image = nil;
    AddOne += 1
    Score.text = "\(AddOne)"
}
```

Note that variable names like `whiteDot`, `smallDot`, `addOne`, and `score` should start with a lower case letter. Class names and types should start with an upper case letter. This is a strong convention in Swift and you should follow it. The language doesn't force you to follow it, but I wouldn't hire a programmer who didn't.